# R (base R) — how to implement render loops inside an IDE environment such as PyCharm (with R plugin) or RStudio

Tags: r, plot, pycharm, cairo

•  I’m using base R + [“cairocore” graphics library](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/cairocore/index.html)

•  I’m trying to get a render() loop going:

```
 i.  taking input from a user
 ii. updating the plot() graphics.
```

Currently, “cairocore” seems to output as a raster that just gets plotted directly by base R plot().

My render loop looks like:

```
key = “”
while (key != “q”) {
   key = readline(prompt=“Enter key: “)
   surface = ... call my code ... # where ‘surface’ is of cairo surface returned 
                                  # by `cairo_surface_image_create` 
                                  # ex: https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/cairocore/articles/demo-drawing-simple-shapes.html)

   plot(cairo_image_surface_get_raster(surface), interpolate=FALSE)
}
```

•  [handy link to example quoted in above code](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/cairocore/articles/demo-drawing-simple-shapes.html)

1. I have tried using `cairo_surface_flush(surface)` before and after the plot() command above, but to no avail:

```
    # inside while loop
    cairo_surface_flush(surface)
    plot(cairo_image_surface_get_raster(surface), interpolate=F)
    cairo_surface_flush(surface)
```

2. I have also tried `dev.flush()` as the final line in the loop, also to no avail:

```
while (key != “q”) {
   key = readline(prompt=“Enter key:”)
   surface = .. call some code ..
   cairo_surface_flush(surface)
   plot(cairo_image_surface_get_raster(surface), interpolate=F)
   cairo_surface_flush(surface)
   dev.flush()
}
```

3. Finally, I see that I can render to x11() on Linux:

```
x11()
... do stuff ...
plot(get_raster())
...
```

But this doesn’t seem to work for me as it opens a new Window every time, rather than updating the first window opened by x11().

***EDIT:  Actually, I had x11() inside the while loop (doh).  Outside of the loop, this solution seems ok. However, this doesn’t solve the issue with the plot not updating inside RStudio or PyCharm-with-R-plugin’s plot-panel.***

4. Ideally, I’d like to get this plot() working inside the plot panel of PyCharm-with-R-plugin or RStudio, rather than x11().
5. I have considered saving the raster to images on the hard drive, and then updating the plot() by reloading the image in the loop. This is a last-resort, solution, though.

**Any insights would be kindly appreciated!**

Thanks!